# Inserting a ROW at the end of a query with Totals for SUM columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I currently have a query that sums up a set of values and groups them by date. The result would look something like this:

```
Date        Item2   Item2   Item3   Item4   Item5
2013-05-31  1       30      0       0       129
2013-06-03  0       90      0       15      78
2013-06-04  0       50      0       1       124
2013-06-05  0       100     0       17      58
2013-06-06  0       24      0       0       105
2013-06-07  0       50      0       1       83
2013-06-10  0       45      2       42      64
2013-06-11  3       43      0       14      90
2013-06-12  2       44      0       36      88
2013-06-13  1       34      0       15      92
```

The query I'm using to retrieve that result looks something like this

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TheDate, 120) 'Date',  
            (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item1,
            (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item2,
            (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item3,
            (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item4,
            (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item5
FROM         Table1 AS a INNER JOIN
                      Table2 AS tab2 ON tab2.Table1ID = a.Table1ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Table3 AS tab3 ON tab3.Table2ID = tab2.Table2ID
WHERE someOtherID = 3 AND UserID = 40
GROUP BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TheDate, 120)
ORDER BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TheDate, 120)
```

What I would like to see is a "GRAND TOTAL" row inserted at the end of the results. The final output would look like

```
Date        Item2   Item2   Item3   Item4   Item5
2013-05-31  1       30      0       0       129
2013-06-03  0       90      0       15      78
2013-06-04  0       50      0       1       124
2013-06-05  0       100     0       17      58
2013-06-06  0       24      0       0       105
2013-06-07  0       50      0       1       83
2013-06-10  0       45      2       42      64
2013-06-11  3       43      0       14      90
2013-06-12  2       44      0       36      88
2013-06-13  1       34      0       15      92
GRAND TOTAL 7       510     2       141     911
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on the best method to go about doing this?

Thank you =D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Union Query would be a quick and dirty way to do this

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TheDate, 120) 'Date',  
        (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item1,
        (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item2,
        (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item3,
        (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item4,
        (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item5
FROM         Table1 AS a INNER JOIN
                  Table2 AS tab2 ON tab2.Table1ID = a.Table1ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  Table3 AS tab3 ON tab3.Table2ID = tab2.Table2ID
WHERE someOtherID = 3 AND UserID = 40
GROUP BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TheDate, 120)
ORDER BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TheDate, 120)

UNION 

    SELECT 'GrandTotal',  
        (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item1,
        (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item2,
        (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item3,
        (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item4,
        (SUM(CASE WHEN itemID = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Item5
FROM         Table1 AS a INNER JOIN
                  Table2 AS tab2 ON tab2.Table1ID = a.Table1ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  Table3 AS tab3 ON tab3.Table2ID = tab2.Table2ID
WHERE someOtherID = 3 AND UserID = 40
```

Comment: That's some fast writing, Elias!

Comment: I'm rather well versed in copy pastaaaa.

Comment: No kidding, very impressive Elias. Thank you =D

Comment: Can't select as answer for a few more minutes... I haven't forgotten you!

Comment: There's actually another way to do it with the `With Rollup` on the group by, might be worth looking into if performance is an issue, EDIT-Sparky has it in his answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13866994/1504882,

Comment: Adding a constant column to each SELECT (`0 as GrandTotal` in the first and `1` in the second) and an ORDER BY at the end (`ORDER BY GrandTotal, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TheDate, 120)`) can guarantee that the grand total is the last row.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the WITH **ROLLUP** option on the **GROUP BY** clause

```
SELECT CASE GROUPING([TheDate])
              WHEN 1 THEN 'GRAND TOTAL'
              ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TheDate, 120) 
              END as Date
   ...
FROM         Table1 AS a INNER JOIN
                  Table2 AS tab2 ON tab2.Table1ID = a.Table1ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  Table3 AS tab3 ON tab3.Table2ID = tab2.Table2ID
WHERE someOtherID = 3 AND UserID = 40
GROUP BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TheDate, 120) WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TheDate, 120)
```